# Where can I get server and platfrom info on each website?

Tags: types, content-management-system, hosting

I need to know hosting company, server type and the platfrom(CMS, etc) and version, client sites are running on ? I know there're sites out there that provide those kind of info...will appricate some suggestion.

Thanks!

Comment: This might be difficult if the hosting company does not provide this information / tries to hide it. Unless the information is provided, you would need to create some sort of "signature" with identifying characteristics for each platform, and look for these. Much like nmap does for operating system guessing.

Answer (score 0):

I think whois.sc will be helpful ... It gives you information about server type, name servers of hosting company and few other ...

Type http://www.whois.sc/yourdomainname.com

Answer (score 0):

There's a nice little initiative by Seth Gottlieb to build a "what CMS is that site running?" field guide. It basically contains a wealth of signatures for different CMS systems, and when you run the (Python) script on a URL it will tell you for each CMS how probable it is to be running that particular site.

It may not give you all the information you're looking for - but it will help you find out what CMS platform a site is running.

The site is currently in [private beta](http://www.cmfieldguide.org/), but you can already check out the code from Github and run it yourself.

Be sure to read [Seth's blogpost](http://www.contenthere.net/2012/05/cm-field-guide-social-coding-for-cms-geeks.html) on this for more information.